# VBA to circumvent SAP disabled/non-clickable buttons

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

Currently I am writing a macro (based on Excel VBA) to automatically run transactions in SAP. Unfortunately, sometimes a button can't be pressed (i.e. blanked out, see screenshot): [image: button cannot be pressed]

But I have no idea how to build this into the macro (if button is not pressable/clickable, resume next).

Here is the screenshot where the button can be pressed/is clickable:
[image: Button pressable]

I have

```
On Error Resume Next
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsHEADER_TABSTRIP1/tabpTABS_OV_FC/ssubG_HEADER_SUBSCREEN1:SAPMV56A:1028/btnSCD_DISPLAY_1").Changeable = True
If Err.Number = 0 Then
   session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsHEADER_TABSTRIP1/tabpTABS_OV_FC/ssubG_HEADER_SUBSCREEN1:SAPMV56A:1028/btnSCD_DISPLAY_1").press
Else
    aSheet.Cells(i, 3) = "No shipment calculation button"
    aSheet.Cells(i, 4) = "Error"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nVT02n"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
   GoTo begin_Loop
```

The line `If "x".changeble=true` does not seem to work (since if the button is clickable, it will still go to the error), neither does the line `If x.setfocus=true`. Which code do I need to fix this problem?

Full code

```
Sub RUN_TEXT_UPDATE2()

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")  'Get the SAP GUI Scripting object
Set sapapp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine 'Get the currently running SAP GUI
Set sapCon = sapapp.Children(0) 'Get the first system that is currently connected
Set session = sapCon.Children(0) 'Get the first session (window) on that connection
Set aSheet = ActiveSheet

On Error GoTo err_handling


session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nVT02N"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

begin_Loop:

For i = 2 To aSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If aSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = "" Then
col1 = Trim(CStr(aSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value))   'Column1  Shipment Number
col2 = Trim(CStr(aSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value))   'Column2  New SCAC


'First entry screen
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVTTK-TKNUM").Text = col1 '"300428742"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

'If the Consider the subsequent documents pop-up exists, automatically click it away
If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
End If

'Go to the "shipment cost calculation" tab
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsHEADER_TABSTRIP1/tabpTABS_OV_FC").Select
'If information pop-up exists, automatically click it away
If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
End If

'press the shipment calculation button

If Not ButtonPressed(session) Then
    aSheet.Cells(i, 3) = "No shipment calculation button"
    aSheet.Cells(i, 4) = "Error"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nVT02n"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
   GoTo begin_Loop


'go into the shipment calculation
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[1]").Select
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
'delete shipment
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[14]").press
'agree to delete it in the pop-up
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-OPTION1").press

If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nVT02N"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
Resume begin_Loop
End If

'go back to VT02n
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nvt02n"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
'Go to tab "stages"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsHEADER_TABSTRIP2/tabpTABS_OV_LG").Select
'If information pop-up exists, automatically click it away
If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
End If
'Change the SCAC number
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsHEADER_TABSTRIP2/tabpTABS_OV_LG/ssubG_HEADER_SUBSCREEN2:SAPMV56A:1032/subLEG_OVER:SAPLSTAG:1300/tblSAPLSTAGVTTS_ALL_CTRL/ctxtVTTS_ALL-TDLNR[3,0]").Text = col2 '"T030626"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
'If information pop-up exists, automatically click it away
If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
End If

'save the order
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
'If information pop-up exists, automatically click it away
If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
End If
If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
End If


'report the orderstatus back to excel
m_status = session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text
If m_status <> "" Then
    aSheet.Cells(i, 3) = m_status
    aSheet.Cells(i, 4) = "UPDATED"
End If

End If

Next

next_SAP_Line:

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nVT02n"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

MsgBox "All SCAC updated/changed"
MsgBox "Forza Ducati!"

Exit Sub

    'If an error occurs, show that in the sheet, macro now crashes when there is a second error, still needs fix
err_handling:    'report the orderstatus back to excel
    m_status = session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text
    aSheet.Cells(i, 3) = m_status
    aSheet.Cells(i, 4) = "Error"

    If i = 0 Then Resume begin_Loop '<--| if error happend before entering loop, the resume at loop start
    'Resume next_SAP_Line '<--| if error happened inside loop, then resume at loop next itaration
    Resume begin_Loop
    
End Sub
```

Function (placed in same module but after the "End Sub"):

```
Function ButtonPressed(session As Object) As Boolean

        On Error GoTo NotPressed

        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsHEADER_TABSTRIP1/tabpTABS_OV_FC/ssubG_HEADER_SUBSCREEN1:SAPMV56A:1028/btnSCD_DISPLAY_1").press
        ButtonPressed = True
        Exit Function

NotPressed:
        ButtonPressed = False
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could work with a function which tries to press the Button

```
Function ButtonPressed(session As Object) As Boolean

        On Error GoTo NotPressed

        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsHEADER_TABSTRIP1/tabpTABS_OV_FC/ssubG_HEADER_SUBSCREEN1:SAPMV56A:1028/btnSCD_DISPLAY_1").press
        ButtonPressed = True
        Exit Function

    NotPressed:
        ButtonPressed = False
    End Function
```

Your code would change to sth like that

```
If Not ButtonPressed(session) Then
    aSheet.Cells(i, 3) = "No shipment calculation button"
    aSheet.Cells(i, 4) = "Error"
    ....
```

EDIT, 2017/05/02
    Your first idea with the property Changeable should work. I think you just need to adjust the code

```
Sub TestIt()
    Dim sapApplication As Object
    Dim session As Object
    Dim SapGuiAuto As Object
    Dim Connection As Object

    If sapApplication Is Nothing Then
        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        Set sapApplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    If Connection Is Nothing Then
        Set Connection = sapApplication.Children(0)
    End If
    If session Is Nothing Then
        Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If

    Dim sBtn As Object 'GuiButton
    Set sBtn = session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]")  ' Back button in the Toolbar
    'Set sBtn = session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]")  ' Save Button in the Toolbar


    If sBtn.Changeable Then
        Debug.Print "Can press button"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Cannot press button"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Storax, Could you please tell me how do I set up the "call" or "GoTo" the buttonpressed function? VBA is giving me errors at the moment. I have set up the function as a separate entity, but using `Call Buttonpressed(session)` does not work.

Comment: Just as I suggested in my answer. Remove everything before else and replace it with If Not ButtonPressed(session) Then

What error do you get? 

Maybe my english is not to good enough but what do you mean wtih  "I have set up the function as a separate entity ", especially "as a separate entity". I have never heard about entity in connection with VBA and Functions.

Comment: Hi Storax. I've added the full code to the original message. Unfortunately I can't seem to really call the function into the code. What I meant with "separate entity" is that it is being described as a function, that can be called upon (so is not specifically just placed in this sub).

Comment: Please use Option Explicit and declare your variables.

Comment: Hi Storax, could you please help me out with that one as well. As what should I declare my variables and will this help with connecting to the function "buttonpressed"? Sorry to keep bothering you.